# Loading Multiple Images from a Folder OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm looking to load all of the images contained in a folder into my program and then create an object for each of these images. I've seen various solutions on line but they only seem to offer for sets of images following a pattern of names.

The general idea is to load each image, create an object for the image and then store each object in the one vector.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

I'll be updating the question with my code as I progress.

Kind Regards.

So Update:

I now have a vector of strings, which contains the file name and I went to create a vector of objects and load each image into the object respectively.

So I am doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i<= fileNames.size(); i++)
{
  allImages.push_back(Image());
  allImages[i].image = imread( format("C:\\PhotoDirectory\\%s, fileNames[i]));
}
```

Where fileNames is the vector of the file names and allImages is the vector of image objects I'm trying to change. It is throwing an exception as it isn't loading the images properly.

Please advise.

Comment: Read all filenames with dirent.h (find it online) and read those images one by one.

Comment: Ahh thank you, that is a great start I'm getting some where. =]

Comment: cv::glob(const string &dirname, vector<string> filenames, bool recurse);

Comment: So I know have a vector<string> of all the filenames, I'm trying to read them in one by one using Imread and then just naming them with the number from the iterator, I'm just struggling a little bit.

I should be using:

for (int i =0; i < fileNames.max_size(); i++)
{
// then I'm unsure as to what to put here..
}

Comment: You can just put one line inside of the loop, something like this: allImages.push_back(imread( format("C:\\PhotoDirectory\\%s, fileNames[i])));

Comment: I think it isn't passing the string properly as an argument though. Any ideas people?